# Hyperlink navigateuri to Childwindow

Tags: xaml, silverlight

hyperlink opens childwindow silverlight

How can I open a childwindow using an hyperlink navigateuri in silverlight?

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="Login" Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" 
    NavigateUri="[ChildWindow]" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="login"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use the `NavigateUri`?

You can just use the `Click` event, like you would do with an ordinary `Button`.

```
<HyperlinkButton
    x:Name="Login"
    Content="login"
    Click="OpenChildWindow"
    Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}"/>
```

and in codebehind:

```
public class MyView : UserControl
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OpenChildWindow(object sender, EventArgs args)
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: using navigateurl isn't possible?

Comment: The `NavigateUri` is only suitable if you need to have the browser navigate to some other URL outside you `Silverlight` app (either leaving the current page or opening a new browsertab).